# use select parameter in subquery as column value

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to set the columnName, databaseName, schemaName etc. dynamically based on a temporary table but cant seem to make it work. i've tried below?

```
Create Table #test(databaseName varchar(128), schemaName varchar(128), columnName varchar(128), datatypeName varchar(128));

INSERT INTO #test ('testDatabase', 'testSchema', 'testTable', 'priceColumn');

SELECT
Case
    WHEN DataType = 'int'
    THEN SELECT MAX(ColumnName) FROM Concat(databaseName, '.', schemaName, '.', tableName)
    ELSE 0
end
FROM #test;

DROP TABLE #test;
```

the expected result is that this below subquery take each line in the row in `#test` table and then query based on these values so it return the maxPrice from that table

```
SELECT MAX(ColumnName) FROM Concat(databaseName, '.', schemaName, '.', tableName)
```

Comment: Am I missing something? 1. You create the temp table. 2. You Select from the temp table. 3. Drop the temp table. But you never insert any rows into it.

Comment: i do that in another select statement which is not included due to the size and complexity of it. i could create test insert though.

Comment: It is hard to tell. It appears the goal is to find the a.b.c nomenclature name of the last field of a given data type.  We need clarification.

Comment: Understood. Can you show some sample data and expected results?

Comment: check now i've updated

Comment: ...Just a side note, If you use @test instead of #test you don't have to drop the temp table as it lives in memory and is automatically de-allocated when the statement loses scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to aggregate on a calculated field while preserving the query flow?

You can try something like this.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(FullName)
FROM
(
    SELECT
         FullName = databaseName+ '.' + schemaName + '.' + columnName,
         *
    FROM
        @test
) AS A
WHERE
    DataTypeName='int'
```

Another example

```
SELECT 
    MAX(FullNameInt),
    MAX(FullNameOther)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        FullNameInt   = CASE WHEN DataTypeName='int' THEN  databaseName+ '.' + schemaName + '.' + columnName ELSE NULL END,
        FullNameOther = CASE WHEN DataTypeName<>'int' THEN databaseName+ '.' + schemaName + '.' + columnName ELSE NULL END,
         *
    FROM
        @test
) AS A
```

Comment: the problem is here this does not enable to add more dataTypeNames like in a case statement

Comment: I updated my answer, however, I no longer think I understand what it is you are attempting.